# javascript - Preserve and Remove Specific Strings From Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, space

I have a textarea value like the following:

```
<br />
The long strings goes here <br/>
New line
```

I want to remove the `<br />` and keep the `<br/>`.

I use this code

```
var contents = $("#textarea").val();
$("#textarea").val(contents.replace("<br />", ""));
```

but it is removing all `br` tags.

How to remove only the `br` tags which is contain space (`<br />`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String.replace() in Javascript will only replace the first match. In order to replace everything, a regex with the /g modifier can be used.

```js
var contents = $("#textarea").val();
$("#textarea").val(contents.replace(/<br \/>/g, ""));
```

```css
#textarea { width: 400px; height: 200px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea"><br />
The long strings goes here <br/>
New line
I want to remove the <br /> and keep the <br/>.
</textarea>
```